# Sorting an ArrayList from alphabetical order to most/least frequent

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to sort my ArrayList (liste) from the most frequent word to the least frequent. So far this is what I've got:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Collections;


public class Ordliste {

private ArrayList<String> liste = new ArrayList<String>();


public void vanligste5(){
Collections.sort(liste);
for(int t = 0; t < 5; t++)
System.out.println(liste.get(t));

}
}
```

The method is supposed to return the 5 most common words in the ArrayList. So far I've managed to sort the list in alphabetical order, but I have no clue as to how I can sort it so that I can return the 5 most common words.

Comment: maintain a frequency map `Map<String,Integer>`, get the top 5

Comment: `TreeMap` recommended

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Please learn to indent code.

Answer (score -4):

combine it all into a string, and then search for each letter specificly

Comment: This completely ignores the question (and is also not a great suggestion any way)